# Youtube Add subscription in android..returning invalid credentials

Tags: java, android, youtube

I am working in a android app in which I  am using insert method on youtube subscription API v3.But it always showing invalid credential error.I have also tested my access token that is not expired.Please help me to implement insert subscription.
My code snippet is

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions");
httppost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httppost.addHeader("part", "snippet");
httppost.addHeader("Authorization", accessToken);
JSONObject channelObj = new JSONObject();
channelObj.put("channelId", channelID);
JSONObject resourceObj = new JSONObject();
resourceObj.put("resourceId", channelObj);
JSONObject snippetObj = new JSONObject();               

snippetObj.put("snippet", resourceObj); 


String message = snippetObj.toString();
httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(message, "UTF8"));
httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
String responseString = StreamUtils.convertToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
```

I am getting following response :-

```
    error: {
  errors: [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "authError",
      "message": "Invalid Credentials",
      "locationType": "header",
      "location": "Authorization",
    }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
  }
}
```